# Jquery adding click function to several spans with the same Class

Tags: jquery, class, click

I'm trying to use jquery to add a `.click()` function to several dynamically generated spans using their class. What I'm trying is essentially:

```
$(".spanClass").click(function () {});
```

I have also tried:

```
$(".spanClass").on("click", function () {});
```

Now, this all works, to an extent. My issue is that the `.click()` only gets assigned to the first span with this class. Every other span with this class does absolutely nothing when I click it. Obviously, I need every span with the class to have the `.click()`.

It may be important to note that my spans are contained inside cells of a table. Each span is in a different cell, and there is only one cell per table row that contains a span.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle of what I'm working with. JSFiddle link

Edit note: Originally this question involved using an ID instead of a class. People noted I should use class instead, and should edit the question if that didn't work.

Edit 2: Added info about tables.

Final edit: Best solution chosen. If you come across this issue, best answer is functioning. My issue was a scripting issue inside my .on("click") function itself.

Comment: IDs should be unique on each page

Comment: Fair enough, but even doing it with a class, it still has the same behavior.

Comment: You should probably edit the question/title to avoid getting downvoted into oblivion. If you want to hit every span with a certain class, $('.classname').click... should work.

Comment: The code you are providing is correct. There must be some other problem, maybe a not valid HTML structure or a problem when dynamically generating the spans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `class` instead of an `id`.

The [**`id`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id) should be unique in the entire page:

> The ID must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the element using getElementById.

Because of this, trying to assign the `click` event to it will fire *only* on the first occurence of the span with `id = spanId`

See example below, and use `.on("click", function())` instead of `.click()`

```
$(".yourspanclass").on("click", function(){
    // do what you need on click 
});
```

see a working example **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HDJUW/)**

Comment: Using this exact syntax, the click method still only fires on the first span with the class. $(".mySpanClass") successfully returns all spans I need the click to work on, but the only one that does anything when clicked is the first.

Comment: did you have a look at my fiddle? each span fires an alert with its own content.. if this code is not working for you, then I think you have something wrong in your HTML. Please create a fiddle with your actual code and post the link

Comment: I've updated my original question with a bit more detail. Aside from being in a couple of extra Divs, this is essentially how my page layout looks. It's very simple. I thought including it being in a table might be causing some sort of issue, but with the JSFiddle, everything still works.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4eLpK/

Comment: double check your HTML :) ps: post your fiddle link in the original question, it will help more there than here

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an HTML issue. The issue is with something in my script. When I remove everything out of the script and just have an alert, it functions on all spans. It's strange, I verified my script with JSHint and everything. It's more strange that the first one functioned, but the rest didn't. Overall, this question is answered though. You've been a great help. Selecting best answer. I don't think I can close.